# JQUERY-UI Draggable with asynchronous selectors

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

Is it possible to use JQUERY-UI draggable with elements that are imported asynchronously using jquery's .load function? I guess that I would need to use .on or .bind, but can't figure out something that works...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add jquery ui function draggable/resizeable after appending/adding it on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308931/add-jquery-ui-function-draggable-resizeable-after-appending-adding-it-on-the-pag)

Comment: Can you share how the dynamic elements are created

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the .load callback to assign the draggable property:

```
$("#containerselector").load('path', function () {
    $(this).find( "elementsthatshouldbedraggableselector" ).draggable();
});
```