# jquery ui draggable asynchronous helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, asynchronous, jquery-ui-draggable

I need to create a jqueryUI draggable helper after an asynchronous function completes, but it doesn't appear that I can return a promise in the helper function. Here's a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/andytaft/a5kfodxq/), and here's the code:

```
function getItems() {
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    dfd.resolve('<div>Hello World</div>')
    return dfd.promise();
}


$( '.my-draggable' ).draggable({
    appendTo: 'body',
    helper: function () {

            /*
            getItems.done(function(items) {
                //Originally tried "return items;" here, which obviously wouldn't work on parent helper function
                return items;
            });
            */

            //return '<div>Hello World</div>'; //this works
            return getItems(); //this does not work
    }
});
```

As my comment mentions, I originally tried to return the items from within the child getItems() function, but forgot that you cannot return a parent function from within a child.

My question has a similar title to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629185/jquery-ui-draggable-with-asynchronous-selectors) post, but it's hard to tell what the post is asking as there are limited details and no code examples.

Comment: not clear what you're trying to accomplish. It also does not look like it's setup right. Wouldn't you use `.done()` versus promise?

Comment: Also should see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308931/add-jquery-ui-function-draggable-resizeable-after-appending-adding-it-on-the-pag

Comment: Twisty, the JqueryUI helper is what displays when you start dragging. I want to build that based on an asynchronous call, as my fiddle shows. You can see the error in the console, or uncomment the first helper return to see it working synchronously. Yes, I would use done() as shown in the commented out helper code if you could return from inside the done() function, but you cannot do that (as I understand). The other stack post has nothing to do with this one, and the accepted fiddle doesn't even work...